# Tokenising CVV for Braintree vaulted cards in hosted fields

Tags: braintree, braintree-vault

I have integrated Braintree HostedFields and it's working fine, Now I am trying to add vault feature to it.

I managed to retrieve all the payment methods from vault using vaultManager in client-side JS.

My question is how do I just tokenize the CVV and not all other details as if a customer selects a card from the displayed option then they won't expecting to enter their card details and expiry date. And if I don't have these data how do I tokenize card.

Do I bother to ask for the CVV at all, because I tried sending the payment method token to server side and charged it by passing it to 'paymentMethodToken' in transaction()->sale()?

I am just not sure what I am supposed to do on the client side once the customer has selected the stored card to pay with.

Comment: You cannot vault CVV but you can ask for the CVV while using a vaulted card. Check out Braintree's [Troubleshooting FAQs}(https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/faq#can-i-verify-the-cvv-when-a-customer-uses-or-updates-a-vaulted-card?)

_disclaimer: I work for Braintree. Please reach out to support@braintreepayments.com with additional questions_

Comment: Hi @turaco Thank you for you reply, I tried it and am getting this error in my browser console 'Uncaught TypeError: braintree.setup is not a function'

Comment: You are utilizing Javascript v2 so `braintree.setup()` must be called after your form container element is created. If `braintree.setup()` runs before the container element exists, the UI may not appear.